# How would you say that you will read a certain book in a certain month, but you won't finish it?

Tags: future-continuous

How would you say that you will read a certain book in a certain month, but you won't finish it? Would the future progressive do the trick. For example:

> I will be reading a book next month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're purely asking about which verb tense you should use, then yes, I'd recommend future continuous. But

(to me) a more natural way of saying this would be

> I **will start** reading a book next month.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say *exactly* that then:

I'll read *Ulysses* next month, but I won't finish it.

Often the best way to say something is to say it, and not depend on hints from the verb tense.

(Of course nobody finishes Ulysses)

Comment: Anyway, if I said "I will be reading a book next month", would it sound natural?  What kind of meaning the tense would communicate in the context?